# Yesod: using widget twice in widget duplicates Julius

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-julius

I have a Yesod widget which loads a widget twice.  The "main" widget looks like:

```
<div .container-fluid .hidden-xs>
  <div .row .no-gutter>
    <div .col-sm-3>
      <!-- sidebar content -->
    <div .col-sm-9>
      <!-- the widget i'm loading twice -->
      ^{dashboardMain}
<nav .visible-xs>
  <!-- sidebar content, also loaded twice, but this widget isn't causing problems (yet) -->
<div .container .visible-xs>
  <div .row .no-gutter>
    ^{dashboardMain}
```

I am running into problems because the Julius file for my `dashboardMain` argument is getting loaded and compiled twice.  Yesod is concatenating two copies of my Julius file together.  This is breaking things elsewhere.

My Haskell code looks like:

```
crmSidebar :: Widget
crmSidebar = defaultSidebarItems -- Using Knockout and a convention based "api"

crmApp :: Widget
crmApp = $(widgetFile "app/crm")

getCRMDashboardR :: Handler TypedContent
getCRMDashboardR = selectRep . provideRep . defaultLayout $ dashboardLayout crmSidebarItems crmApp
```

The Haskell compiles fine, but like I said, I am getting a runtime Javascript error because of how Yesod/Julius is processing my widget.  What should I do?

---

Edit 1:

I'm using KnockoutJS, which requires `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` to be applied exactly once.  Changing that isn't an option.

`dashboardLayout` is defined by

```
dashboardLayout :: String -> Widget -> Widget -> Widget
dashboardLayout sidebarHeader dashboardSidebarItems dashboardMain = $(widgetFile "layouts/dashboard")
```

Comment: What are the exact errors you are getting? How is dashboardMain defined? If the errors are related to javascript global variables clashing/overriding one another(which sounds like the case), consider using javascript constructs such as self executing functions(thus creating a local scope for each script) or using newIdent to give unique identifiers to the variables.